# Django Haystack ElasticSearch Python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, django-haystack, python-3.4

my plan is to get Django with an ElasticSearch backend running using Python3 on a Debian 7.5-64bit machine.

I'll explain every single step, cause i'm nor a professional admin, neither a ready developer.
Not to forget, i'm dealing with this problem the third evening and i feels like i have tried every single tip in the internet.

First, I unpacked, configured, made, made test, made install Python-3.4.1 in my /usr/local/. This created links/bins in usr/local/bin. So i created symlinks from /usr/bin to /usr/local/bin and "installed" different python3 (3.2 from within debian, and 3.4) with update-alternatives. I created alternatives for python3 and python3-config.

The same with Java 8u11 Server-JRE.

I went on installing Django 1.6.5, Haystack 2.1, pyelasticsearch 0.6.1 with at least EVERY pip installed in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin  (pip has also installed requests 2.3.0, simplejson 3.6.0, six 1.7.3).

Meanwhile i also installed pyes 0.99.2 and urllib3 1.9. Both with pip.

Django is configured and running, also apache with mod-wsgi modul. I created a django project and an app (no models yet).
Elasticsearch is also running, but without any indizes yet.

To my project/settings.py i edited and added:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {...
'haystack'}
...
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'NAME': 'haystack',
}
...
}
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
},
}
```

When i run ./manage.py from within projectfolder I get following error:

```
./manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 131, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named ElasticsearchSearchEngine.base
```

And like the shebang in manage.py says, this so uses python2.7.
Then forcing my python 3.4 interpeter:

```
python3 ./manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2221, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine'; 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 131, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine'; 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend' is not a package
```

A ls shows, that the file is there, and with an editor i see, that the class exists
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py

Did I forget ANYTHING? Should there be anything in "PYTHONPATH" which is under python-lib directory? Which information could also be important?

At least: Is this setup even possible? Did i understand the structure of django-haystack and database-backend correct?

Please help me. I'm tired of and done with the docu and samples from django, haystack, elasticsearch and the most targeting google hits.

Answer (score 0):

syncdb command will try to sync your models with the database. Django is not able to interpret ElasticsearchSearchEngine as a database. You should use correct ENGINE value corresponding to the database you are using.

e.g. For MySQL

```
ENGINE='django.db.backends.mysql'
```

Do you intend to use database at all? If not then do not run syncdb.

Comment: I wanted to use elasticsearch as my database. Is this wrong? a year ago, we put lots of logfiles to an elasticsearch-hadoop cluster (for fast seraching) and set the elasticsearch to write it's indizes to diks few times a day. I think, that should also be possible here and using the nice django-DB features on top of ugly elasticsearch-json-query-foo.
Should i better use a fast MySQL-fork as a database and configure elasticsearchSearchEngine just as an searchengine?

Comment: No it is not wrong at all. You can use elasticsearch as a NOSQL store for sure. For that you need to set `DATABASES = {}` in settings.py. Django is an ORM system which is designed to work with traditional RDBMS databases and you will not be able to utilize django's database related commands.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your database setting is wrong. You should use any of the database engine here like :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}
```

if you choose to use sqlite database in your project.